# Input terminal problems and map

Tags: c++

I am using map to count the occurence of words. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    map<string,int>wordcount;
    string s;

    while (cin>> s && s!="red")
        ++wordcount[s];

    while (cin>>s &&  s!="red")

    cout << s << "   " << wordcount[s] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I start the program, type words and at the last line enter the word "red", but it does not do anything. Then I type "red" the second time and it outputs:

> press any key to continue

what is wrong?

Comment: Why do you use exactly the same loop test twice? It means that the second loop can't possibly run.

Comment: @Marcelo: The "s" gets a new value before the s != "red" is evaluated, so the second loop does run.

Comment: @Mattias: You got me there! Can I just suggest, then, that this is a rather obscure way to write the logic? Is this forced upon you by a predetermined input format? Do you really want the input file to decide which keys to print out (and in which order), or is this just an unnecessarily round-about way to print all the keys?

Comment: @Marcelo: I have to agree with you there. This isn't my code and I would have solved this differently. Probably the first thing I would do is complain about "red" having a special meaning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too groggy to write here, but I'll try a second time. :)

If you write a lot of words, it will count them up until you write "red".
The second loop will print the count for the words you input, but if you put "red" right away it will simply terminate the program without printing anything.

Try running the program with the following input:

```
one
two
two
red
zero
one
two
red
```

Comment: A stream can be converted to a bool.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong. Visual Studio will automatically [`PAUSE`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/pause.mspx?mfr=true) the program before it ends to prevent the console window from closing, when you "Run without Debugging".

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to receive a list of words, fill each word's number of occurrences into a map, and print it.

So, instead of the second while loop, you need to iterate **on the map that you created** and print the count for each word.

You can learn [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/begin/) how to print the map's contents.